# How to pass variable into ggplot aes / ..y.. part of function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking at passing `transform` into the below function to be able to line up the secondary axis... however, I get an error:

`Error in y * transform : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

```
library(ggplot2)
a.samples <- rbeta(10000, 25, 75)
b.samples <- rbeta(10000, 35, 65)

df <- data.frame(x = b.samples/a.samples)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram(fill = 'grey50', alpha = .6)

transform <- max(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$ymax)

p + geom_line(aes(y = ..y.. * transform), stat='ecdf') + # error here
    geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = 'dashed') +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./transform, name = "ecdf")) +
    guides(color = FALSE)
```

If I explicitly write the value `1260` into the aes argument, it works.

`...geom_line(aes(y = ..y.. * 1260), stat='ecdf')...`

Comment: Try `as.numeric(transform)`

Comment: Doesn't work... `Error in as.numeric(transform) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'`

Comment: Use `transform; str(transform)` and tell me what it outputs

Comment: Could you run my example? My code is reproducible... it outputs: `[1] 1260
 num 1260`

Comment: What version of ggplot2 and R are you using?

Comment: `R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)` `ggplot2_2.2.1`

Comment: Your code works on my Win 10 machine running `R 3.5.0` and dev `ggplot2 2.2.1.9000 2018-05-20 Github (tidyverse/ggplot2@acbaec7)`

Comment: Thanks for checking.. I'll try downloading dev version (suggested for plotly anyway hah).. I was able to use `aes_string` to get the desired output on my current setup

Answer (score 1):

Was able to get this to work with `aes_string`

```
p + geom_line(aes_string(y = paste0('..y.. * ', transform)), stat='ecdf') + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = 'dashed') +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./transform, name = "ecdf")) +
    guides(color = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

So your above code oddly worked for me without any other errors other than the binwidths being off so I don't know what was generating the error but I just adjusted it with adding stat_ecdf()

```
library(ggplot2)
a.samples <- rbeta(10000, 25, 75)
b.samples <- rbeta(10000, 35, 65)

df <- data.frame(x = b.samples/a.samples)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) + geom_histogram(fill = 'grey50', alpha = .6)

transform <- max(ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]]$ymax)
transform
p + stat_ecdf(aes(y = ..y.. * transform),geom = "line") + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = 'dashed') +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./transform, name = "ecdf")) +
  guides(color = FALSE)
```

Comment: Tried restarting my R but still getting an error, even with this code. Wonder what my issue is, although I was able to eventually get it to work with `aes_string`.. thanks for responding though